# TikZ path with rounded corners and decorations.markings not working as expected (pos=0.0 at wrong location)

Tags: positioning, tikz-styles, decorations, rounded-corners

I want to put small round markings at fixed distances on a six-pointed star.

There are two problems though: `pos=0.0` is not at the expected location, but slightly shifted possibly due to the `rounded corners` style. I want to have small dots on all the corners, how can I fix this?

Furthermore, there is an additional problem: when using a step size of 0.013888, the MWE does not compile. However, with a step size of 0.05 is used, it does compile. The error is: `Dimension too large` (on line 20).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=0pt},
  decoration={
  markings,
  mark=between positions 0 and 1.0 step 0.013888 with %
    {\node[draw, circle, minimum width=1pt,anchor=center]{};}}] 
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5} {
    \path (12,-3) ++(30+60*\x:3) coordinate (s\x);
    \path (12,-3) ++(60*\x:1.7320508076) coordinate (si\x);
  }
  \draw[postaction={decorate},thick,rounded corners] (si0) -- (s0) -- %
    (si1) -- (s1) -- (si2) -- (s2) -- (si3) -- (s3) -- (si4) -- (s4) -- %
    (si5) -- (s5) -- cycle;      

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1):

I am just a newbie when it comes to working with tikz but I gather that the algorithm to calculate rounded corners is such that they cannot go exactly through the nodes (indicated by red circles below).  I have drawn two paths to show this, a black one with the rounded corner, and a red one without rounded corners but showing the decorations (small circles) at each node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=0pt},
  decoration={
  markings,
  mark=between positions 0.0 and 1.0 step 0.08333 with %
         %% 0.08333 \approx 1/12
    {\node[draw, circle, minimum width=3pt,anchor=center]{};}}] 
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5} {
    \path (12,-3) ++(30+60*\x:3) coordinate (s\x);
    \path (12,-3) ++(60*\x:1.7320508076) coordinate (si\x);
  }
  \draw[thick,rounded corners] (si0) -- (s0) -- %
    (si1) -- (s1) -- (si2) -- (s2) -- (si3) -- (s3) -- (si4) -- (s4) -- %
    (si5) -- (s5) -- cycle;      
  \draw[postaction={decorate}, color=red] (si0) -- (s0) -- %
    (si1) -- (s1) -- (si2) -- (s2) -- (si3) -- (s3) -- (si4) -- (s4) -- %
    (si5) -- (s5) -- cycle;  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: star with circles]

Answer (score 1):

Without use of the `decorations.markings`, for fun :-)

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style = {circle, draw, semithick,  
                inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt,
                node contents={}},
                        ]
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,5} 
{
\path (30+60*\x:3) coordinate (s\x)  ++ (30+60*\x:-2pt) node [dot];
\path (60*\x:1.73) coordinate (si\x) ++ (60*\x:+1pt) node [dot];
  }
\draw[semithick,rounded corners=4pt] 
    (si0) -- (s0) -- (si1) -- (s1) -- (si2) -- (s2) -- (si3)
          -- (s3) -- (si4) -- (s4) -- (si5) -- (s5) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]