# How to put a tikz node on the rounded corner?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am interested in the line-to operation |- (or -| ) with rounded corner. Now, I would like to add a node on the rounded corner. But the node then appears not on the rounded corner -- it is rather on the `original corner'. How to force this node to be on the line?

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [rounded corners=1cm] (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the output

[image]

*I know it can be done with `to` and also with `controls`* (though I couldn't get the desired result without a bit of tweaking)

I feel tweaking is not the right thing to do. It is like doing paint in tikz; if we are doing tweaking, why not draw on a WYSIWYG drawing software or geometry software and export?

So, my question is
**Is there any way to put a node exactly on a rounded corner?**
(preferably without using `to` or `controls`; but if you can do them in a rather neat way, you are more than welcome)

Oh, I almost forgot. *Just being curious, is there a name for this |- or -| operation?*

Thank you

Comment: there is a similar (unanswerd, unfortunately) question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397589/tikz-path-with-rounded-corners-and-decorations-markings-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @Rmano, The problem you mentioned seems to show a different issue. Sure, rounded corner is messing with markings; but still *markings are on the line*.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with markings... but finding the "center" position is still done by guessing.

Comment: I update the answer...

Comment: I now understand that `controls` gives a nice output if we declare a coordinate beforehand. `\path (0,0) |-\coordinate(midpt) (2,3); \draw (0,0) ..controls (midpt).. node{mid} (2,3);` gives satisfactory output in most cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends a bit on what do you intend for "middle"; I would use intersections generally. In this example, I am using as "middle point" the intersection of the curved path and the rectangle formed by the two parts for the red dot, and with a 45 degree angle in the case of the blue one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rounded corners=1cm] (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (one) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (two) at (2,3);
    \draw [rounded corners=1cm, name path=A] (one)|-(two);
    % remove draw=red
    \path [draw=red, name path=B] (one -| two) -- (two -| one);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=A and B, by=DOT}];
    \node [circle, red, fill] at (DOT){};
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (one) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (two) at (2,3);
    \draw [rounded corners=1cm, name path=A] (one)|-(two);
    \coordinate (mid) at  (one |- two);
    % remove draw=blue
    \path [draw=blue, name path=B] (mid) -- ($(mid)+(1,-1)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=A and B, by=DOT}];
    \node [circle, blue, fill] at (DOT){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the snippet above]

You cal also use a decoration, but in this case you have to guessestimate the `pos` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{markpos/.style args={#1 at #2}{decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\coordinate(#1);}},postaction={decorate}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rounded corners=1cm] (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rounded corners=1cm, markpos=mymark at 0.6] (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
    \node [circle, red, fill] at (mymark){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Another one]

Comment: I accepted this because it solves the problem. Thank you @Rmano. Still, i am curious as to whether there is some easier method.

Comment: I mean, intersections seems to be a broadly useful technique. Yet, can we keep the code shorter (neatly)?

Comment: Sure we can; creating macros and similar things as ever. I've been verbose on purpose... ;-)

Comment: Wow, one parameter is fine I guess

Answer (score 5):

Here is a broad approach using node anchor that can certainly be improved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rounded corners=1cm] (0,0)|-node[below right]{mid}(2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this be tweaking? If the node was simply a dot (as in my original application), we will need to tweak the node distance. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CyriacAntony yes in this solution the distance depend on the node content. I think it may be  doable to automate the node position so it become independent of the content.

Comment: Automating node position independent of the content sounds good. Yet, we will have to change the node position if the rounding is more (or less), don't we? For instance: `rounded corners=3cm`

Comment: @Cyriac yes exactly that's what I mean! I will think about it as soon as possible. I am in hurry now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xshift` and `yshift` to place the node properly. The value of these shifts can be obtained with simple geometry calculation.

```
  \draw [rounded corners=\rndc] (0,0)|-node[xshift=0.293*\rndc),yshift=-0.293*\rndc)]{mid}(2,3);
```

The number `0.293` is `1-1/sqrt(2)`.

[image]

The complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)|-node{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\rndc{1cm}
  \draw [rounded corners=\rndc] (0,0)|-node[xshift=0.293*\rndc),yshift=-0.293*\rndc)]{mid}(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The bracket `)` after `\rndc)` seems wrong, but it makes surprisingly no error. But it could be removed.