# Connecting a path to the corner of a node with the rounded corners option

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, rounded-corners

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\Large
\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,draw,rounded corners]{surname}{Kennedy} was killed by Lee Harvey Oswald
 the sniper.
\vspace{5pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) --++ (-1,-0) --++(0,-1) node [below, draw, anchor=north west, xshift=-2cm]{\footnotesize b. May 29, 1917, d. November 22, 1963, often referred to by his initials JFK, 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this code, the path is connected to the south west corner of the node. But when I make the node `rounded corners`, the path doesn't connect to the corner:

[image]

The closest solution to this problem is at [How to put a tikz node on the rounded corner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466644/how-to-put-a-tikz-node-on-the-rounded-corner) but it doesn't answer connecting a path into the rounded corner.

How to connect the path into the corner of this rounded-cornered node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rounded corner` is default to `4pt`, so just go diagonal half that to connect to the border.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\Large
\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt, draw, rounded corners]{surname}{Kennedy} was killed by Lee Harvey Oswald
 the sniper.
\vspace{5pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue, thick, ->] ([shift={(45:2pt)}]surname.south west) -- (surname.south west) --++ (-1,-0) --++(0,-1) node [below, draw, anchor=north west, xshift=-2cm]{\footnotesize b. May 29, 1917, d. November 22, 1963, often referred to by his initials JFK, 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: "Kennedy" framed and connected to a line]

Comment: +1 Using `[shift={(45:2pt)}` is even better. This could also be added as an option to the other question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using `[shift={(45:2pt)}` is a good idea.  It's supposed to give a 45 degree angle to the path but in my computer it didn't. It kept on horizontally. I use, `lualatex` on TeXLive 2020. I've deleted the .aux file and compiled twice again and the path's connection part is still horizontal. What could be wrong?

Comment: Ops! I forgot adding the `-- (surname.south west)` to the path. After I've added it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

#### Adaptations

- I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466674/123129) of your linked question:

```
([xshift=0.293*\rndc, yshift=0.293*\rndc] surname.south west)
```

- made use of `-|` connection

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\def\rndc{4pt}

\begin{document}
\Large
\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,draw,rounded corners=\rndc]{surname}{Kennedy} was killed by Lee Harvey Oswald the sniper.
\vspace{5pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[blue,thick,->]
        ([xshift=0.293*\rndc, yshift=0.293*\rndc] surname.south west)
        -- (surname.south west)
        -|++(-1,-1) node [below, draw, anchor=north west, xshift=-2cm]{%
            \footnotesize b. May 29, 1917, d. November 22, 1963, often referred to by his initials JFK, 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works out quite fine. But because another answer came earlier and it worked out too, I have selected is as accepted.